# a statistical question which i thought it was a binomial distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

A mathematics textbook has 100 pages on which typographical errors in the equations could occur. Suppose there are in fact two pages with errors. What is the probability that a random sample of 20 pages will contain at least one error?

read some solutions online, it says it is poisson, why is it?
and i seem don't quit understand [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P8qq.jpg)

Comment: Both are incorrect.  It should be a [hyper geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
P(\text{at least one error})&=1-P(\text{no error})\\
&=1-\dfrac{\binom20\binom{98}{20}}{\binom{100}{20}}
\end{align}
i.e. choose $0$ out of $2$ pages with errors and choose $20$ out of $98$ correct pages.

However, since the number of wrong pages is small compared to the total number of pages, Poisson can be used as a quick **approximation**. (But for this case, it's not very appropriate anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the same birthday problem.

$1 - (\frac{98}{100}\cdot \frac{97}{99}..............\frac{79}{81}) = 1 - (\frac{98!}{78!}\cdot \frac{80!}{100!}) = .3612$